# Selecting a checkbox in html table containing handlebar, expressjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, handlebars.js

I have a html table in a form in which the rows of table are populated using handebars. I want to select some rows of the table using checkbox. The form makes a post request. I am using express.js framework for the same. The requiremment is that when the form is submitted the json should have a field named 'checked' which should have value true or 1 if the row was selected. Please help me in solving the issue.

**Following is the snippet of the html**

```
 <form  id='form1'>

<table border="1">

{{#each ElectrnicsResults}}
    <tr>
            <td>{{Product}}</td>
            <td>{{Description}}</td>
            <td>{{price}}</td>
            <td>{{quantity}}</td>
            <td>
          <input type='checkbox' id="check">
            </td>
            <td style="display:none">
                    <input type="hidden" name="electronicsId" value="{{electronicsId}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="Product" value="{{Product}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="Description" value="{{Description}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{price}}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="{{quantity}}" />
                </td>


    </tr>
{{/each}}

</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" >

 </form>
```

**Following is the javascript code using JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/submitValues',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function() {
               alert("Submitted!"); // for testing
            }
        });
        return false;
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the form is created dynamically, you'll have to parse the results dynamically as well.

First, you'll want to attach a `name` field to each `input type=checkbox` element. This name needs to be unique to each `ElectrnicsResults` (perhaps something like the `ID` field).

Then, in your backend code when parsing the form details, you'll can again loop through each relevant `ElectrnicsResults` and check the `req.body.{UNIQUE_NAME_FIELD_VALUE}` for each checkbox, and act accordingly.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that with example or a snippet